# Setting RequestParam with default value is always null when value is set

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am creating a rest method that could handle an optional parameter(gender in this case) using RequestParam annotation. But the gender value is always taken as null. (spring version 4.0.0) second param is considered correctly though.

Sample: http://localhost:8080/bll-0.1/qry/gender/female/age/40

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/age/{age}", "/gender/{gender}/age/{age}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getByAge(@RequestParam(value="gender", defaultValue="unknown") String gender, @PathVariable("age") int age) throws Exception {...}
```

Thanks in advance. 
Pankaj

Comment: Why are u using RequestParam and not PathParam for gender?

Comment: what you have there is a PathVariable, not a RequestParam.

Comment: I don't see any request param at your sample URL, it should look like this to have a requestparam  http://localhost:8080/bll-0.1/qry/gender/female/age/40?gender=Male

Comment: Thanks Babl. I changed from gender from Pathvariable to RequestParam. and was still holding on to older query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Like Juned said in comments, use @PathVariable for gender as well.

```
public @ResponseBody String getByAge(@PathVariable("gender") String gender, @PathVariable("age") int age) throws Exception {...}
```

If you want optional parameter and it's not a problem if you have request paramter then your url should be somewhat like `http://localhost:8080/bll-0.1/qry/age/40?gender=female` and you can use `@RequestParam`

```
public @ResponseBody String getByAge(@RequestParam(value="gender", defaultValue="unknown") String gender, @PathVariable("age") int age) throws Exception {...}
```

Comment: But I want gender as optional. PathVariable doesn't give me that freedom. I changed it from Pathvariable to @RequestParam, Added a new requestmapping for that  but forgot to change the query. Thanks.

Comment: You can have two methods: one with both param and one with only one param.